# Can "sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /" on Linux destroy a Windows partition if run using dual boot?

Tags: linux, sudo, rm

I'm not crazy enough to test it out, but I'm curious to know if `sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` would have any effect on other operating systems on the disk, or if it's safely contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on whether the partition is mounted.

If the partition is mounted, then the command **will recurse into it** and delete all files. It will not, strictly speaking, destroy the partition - the partion will still be there. However, it will be empty.

If the partition is not mounted, it will not be changed.